# Drag and drop a shape from HTML5 canvas to another

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

Consider there is two canvas. I would like to drag a shape which is in a canvas and drop it to another canvas. Can it be possible?

Thanks to understand my question.

Comment: Are you using any framework? With pure canvas this would be cumbersome, because there's no concept of shapes (only pixsls).

Comment: I dont aware of any framework. If you can suggest something that would be great. Thanks

Comment: [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/) looks pretty straight-forward, but I'm not sure if it supports dragging between two canvases.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. It's not going to be particularly easy, though. I'll give you the basic idea. You'll need to do the math and implementation yourself:

1. Figure out the source shape boundaries.
2. Get that pixel data and use to it to construct a new canvas element on top of the old one. You'll use this to deal with dragging.
3. Implement dragging logic for this temporary canvas.
4. Detect "drop" on target canvas, figure out where the bounds hit on it. Replace target pixel data with the data on the draggable.
5. Get rid of the draggable canvas.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question, but won't the shape be on whichever context you draw it to?

**Example:**

```
context1.drawImage(...);
context2.drawImage(...);
```

Simply change the context?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to do is to use DOM proxy objects, catching the mouse event, overlaying the canvas. Because the code in the question is very complex considering using a library:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/

From canvas to canvas is still something you need to figure out youself, as the use case is very rare and you need to animate the object when dragging is not on the canvas.  Definitely possible, but extreme complex.